# Panasonc GH5 4K 10 Bit 25p (cannot allocate memory)

Tags: ffmpeg

I am converting GH5 files with the following script. With my Notebook I get no error and it goes through but at my desktop workstation I get this error. Anybody an idea. I convert 4K 10Bit Panasonic GH5 files to AVID HQX files. No error at the notebook but the desktop pc produces this error message. OS is windows 7 just new installed because of this. Same MeGUI and FFMPEG version and development server.

`enter code here`

```
D:\Test>for %f in (*.mov) do "C:\Program Files (x86)\MeGUI\tools\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.e
xe" -i "%~f" -c:a pcm_s16le -c:v dnxhd -profile:v dnxhr_hqx "%~nf_test.mov"

D:\Test>"C:\Program Files (x86)\MeGUI\tools\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe" -i "P1011064.MOV"
 -c:a pcm_s16le -c:v dnxhd -profile:v dnxhr_hqx "P1011064_test.mov"
ffmpeg version 3.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --e
nable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libblur
ay --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopu
s --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --ena
ble-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-lib
x264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-z
lib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-cuda --enable-c
uvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-l
ibmfx
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 005a7860] decoding for stream 0 failed
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'P1011064.MOV':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537986816
    compatible_brands: qt  pana
    creation_time   : 2017-11-19T16:16:23.000000Z
    com.panasonic.Semi-Pro.metadata.xml: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" st
andalone="no" ?>
                    : <ClipMain xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-inst
ance" xmlns="urn:schemas-Professional-Plug-in:Semi-Pro:ClipMetadata:v1.0">
                    :   <ClipContent>
                    :     <GlobalClipID>060A2B340101010501010D2113000000171BA845
E82C2C3470010E90B8D50052</GlobalClipID>
                    :     <Duration>84</Duration>
                    :     <EditUnit>1/25</EditUnit>
                    :     <EssenceList>
                    :       <Video>
                    :         <Codec BitRate="150">H264_422_LongGOP</Codec>
                    :         <ActiveLine>2160</ActiveLine>
                    :         <ActivePixel>3840</ActivePixel>
                    :         <BitDepth>10</BitDepth>
                    :         <FrameRate>25p</FrameRate>
                    :         <TimecodeType>NonDrop</TimecodeType>
                    :         <StartTimecode>07:12:44:18</StartTimecode>
                    :       </Video>
                    :       <Audio>
                    :         <Channel>2</Channel>
                    :         <SamplingRate>48000</SamplingRate>
                    :         <BitsPerSample>16</BitsPerSample>
                    :       </Audio>
                    :     </EssenceList>
                    :     <ClipMetadata>
                    :       <Rating>0</Rating>
                    :       <Access>
                    :         <CreationDate>2017-11-19T16:16:23+02:00</CreationD
ate>
                    :         <LastUpdateDate>2017-11-19T16:16:23+02:00</LastUpd
ateDate>
                    :       </Access>
                    :       <Device>
                    :         <Manufacturer>Panasonic</Manufacturer>
                    :         <ModelName>DC-GH5</ModelName>
                    :       </Device>
                    :       <Shoot>
                    :         <StartDate>2017-11-19T16:16:23+02:00</StartDate>
                    :       </Shoot>
                    :     </ClipMetadata>
                    :   </ClipContent>
                    :   <UserArea>
                    :     <AcquisitionMetadata xmlns="urn:schemas-Professional-P
lug-in:P2:CameraMetadata:v1.2">
                    :       <CameraUnitMetadata>
                    :         <Gamma>
                    :           <CaptureGamma>CINELIKE_D</CaptureGamma>
                    :         </Gamma>
                    :         <Gamut>
                    :           <CaptureGamut>BT.709</CaptureGamut>
                    :         </Gamut>
                    :       </CameraUnitMetadata>
                    :     </AcquisitionMetadata>
                    :   </UserArea>
                    : </ClipMain>
                    :
  Duration: 00:00:03.36, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 174710 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:2:2) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv422p10le(
tv, bt709), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 147582 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn,
50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-11-19T16:16:23.000000Z
      timecode        : 07:12:44:18
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: pcm_s16be (twos / 0x736F7774), 48000 Hz, stereo, s1
6, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-11-19T16:16:23.000000Z
      timecode        : 07:12:44:18
    Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-11-19T16:16:23.000000Z
      timecode        : 07:12:44:18
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> dnxhd (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16be (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[dnxhd @ 0542fe60] Cannot allocate memory.
[dnxhd @ 04d508a0] ff_frame_thread_encoder_init failed
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output s
tream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!

D:\Test>pause
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159926/discussion-on-question-by-sebastian-panasonc-gh5-4k-10-bit-25p-cannot-allocate).